# WshShell.Run of executable from UserProfile variable directory

Tags: vbscript

I thought I had this correct but I don't.  I'm trying to have an executable called from user profile directory.  The variable is not expanding properly.  This is the code example:

```
userProfilePath = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%")
exePath = userProfilePath + "\test1.exe"
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"")
WshShell.Run """ & exePath & """
```

When the VBScript runs, it doesn't properly show the path of ("C:\Users\John Doe\test1.exe").  What am I missing on how to use the variable and string correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quoting is incorrect. `WScript.Shell` must be in a single pair of double quotes, and if you want to add double quotes before and after the value of a variable you need to use either `Chr(34)`

```
WshShell.Run Chr(34) & exePath & Chr(34)
```

or sequences of 4 double quotes:

```
WshShell.Run """" & exePath & """"
```

The reason for the 4 consecutive double quotes is that VBScript string literals must begin and end with a double quote, and nested double quotes inside a string literal must be escaped by doubling them (so they don't prematurely terminate the string). Your literal `""" & exePath & """` defines the literal text `" & exePath & "`, not the value of the variable `exePath` between two double qoutes.

With that said, in your particular case you don't need the whole concatenation shebang, because the `Run` method can handle environment variables by itself. The following code should suffice for your needs:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run """%USERPROFILE%\test1.exe"""
```